# More information on one column vs Little information on more column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, performance

I create image upload and watch galery feature and I store each user image like this:
When user upload new image I update images column and It became like user_id_img1,user_id_img2,user_id_img3.For Fast SQL purpose is it good idea?Or shoud I insert new rows for each image from user?

Comment: Do you want to access all the images by a user? And can you give us the table structure (ideally create table statement).

Comment: @Malinga user_id(int) image_url(text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the very basic stuff of database design, like multiplication table in arithmetic.

**A column in database should always contain single value.**

For the purpose of storing multiple data you have rows in your database. Therefore, always add another row for the each image.

Comment: Great answer! Can You give me link to read more about it,It is really interesting

Comment: I am doubtful about it,but when sql select images it will be more fast if all images in one column because sql only will choose one rows,isn't it?

Comment: Please forget about performance. You will ruin your application trying to speed it up.